# I am trying to use clipboard object in class project of vb.net but I can't seem to be able to use it

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to get clipboard text in vb.net class project but the clipboard object is not working

```
Dim clipText As String = String.Empty
If Clipboard.ContainsText Then
     clipText = Clipboard.GetText()
End If
```

I am using this code but its giving me error

`Dim clipboardText As String = System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.GetText()`
I am trying to use this but system. Windows doesn't have .forms but it has .input and .others what am I missing I tried referencing it from the references but it doesn't seem to work either

Comment: It sounds like you didn't create a Windows Forms project to begin with. What type of project did you create?

Comment: There is a clipboard class in `System.Windows` if you are working in WPF instead of Windows Forms.  You could also consider using `My.Computer.Clipboard`.

Comment: But note that if this is a class project, you may be expected to take a specific approach.  Make sure you have the right project type, and, if the clipboard is something specific to your assignment, you're using the right location for it.

Answer (score 0):

This is from a little project where i load code from a SQLite DB into a RichTextBox then click a button to copy that code to the clip board.

```
Private Sub btnCopySelCode_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCopySelCode.Click
    CopySelected()
End Sub
Public Sub CopySelected()
    Dim start = rtbViewCode.SelectionStart
    Dim substring = rtbViewCode.Text.Substring(0, start)
    Dim words = substring.Split(New String() {" ", vbCrLf}, StringSplitOptions.None)
    Dim gvW = rtbViewCode.SelectedText
    Dim count = gvW.Length
    If count <= 0 Then
        gvalertType = "14"
        frmAlert.ShowDialog()
        rtbViewCode.Focus()
        Return
    End If
    Clipboard.SetText(gvW)
    ansQ()
End Sub
```